# Grouping , Filter and map particular elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, mapping

Hi I try to do a complex mapping using single XSLT tranformation. But I tried for-each and apply-templates, could not even come close to the requirement.

Below are the conditions.

1)Group employee elements by concatenating Firstname,Lastname and DeptNo

2) In unique employee element If Primary contact is 'Y' map the corresponding records Mobile number to the Target

3)  If PrimaryConcat element with 'Y' value is not present, then map Mobile number from the employee record where PrimaryConcat value is 'N'

4) If both 'Y' and 'N' is not present, Dont map the mobile number

There will be more than million Employee elements coming in the input with address , contact details etc. I have given here an example only with mobile number.

Thanks

**INPUT XML**

```
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <PrimaryContact>Y</PrimaryContact>
        <Name>
            <FirstName>Paul</FirstName>
            <LastName>Hecht</LastName>
        </Name>
        <DeptNo>10008072</DeptNo>
        <MobNo>78952646</MobNo>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <PrimaryContact>N</PrimaryContact>
        <endDate>0001-01-15T00:00:00.000Z</endDate>
        <Name>
            <FirstName>Paul</FirstName>
            <LastName>Hecht</LastName>
        </Name>
        <DeptNo>10008072</DeptNo>
        <MobNo>54646544</MobNo>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <PrimaryContact/>
        <Name>
            <FirstName>Chris</FirstName>
            <LastName>Grey</LastName>
        </Name>
        <DeptNo>10001760</DeptNo>
        <MobNo>1378956</MobNo>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <PrimaryContact>N</PrimaryContact>
        <Name>
            <FirstName>Chris</FirstName>
            <LastName>Grey</LastName>
        </Name>
        <DeptNo>10001760</DeptNo>
        <MobNo>78941236</MobNo>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <PrimaryContact/>
        <Name>
            <FirstName>Jessica</FirstName>
            <LastName>Thruman</LastName>
        </Name>
        <DeptNo>10008022</DeptNo>
        <MobNo>7895264446</MobNo>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <PrimaryContact/>
        <Name>
            <FirstName>Jessica</FirstName>
            <LastName>Thruman</LastName>
        </Name>
        <DeptNo>10008022</DeptNo>
        <MobNo>5464786544</MobNo>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT:**

```
<Employees>
    <Employee>
        <Name>
            <FirstName>Paul</FirstName>
            <LastName>Hecht</LastName>
        </Name>
        <MobNo>78952646</MobNo>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Name>
            <FirstName>Chris</FirstName>
            <LastName>Grey</LastName>
        </Name>
        <MobNo>78941236</MobNo>
    </Employee>
    <Employee>
        <Name>
            <FirstName>Jessica</FirstName>
            <LastName>Thruman</LastName>
        </Name>
        <MobNo/>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 I tried to implement your description as http://xsltransform.net/bdxtqL/1 which does

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="Employees">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="Employee" group-by="string-join((Name/(FirstName, LastName), DeptNo), '|')">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="Name"/>
                    <MobNo>
                        <xsl:value-of select="(current-group()[PrimaryContact = 'Y']/MobNo, current-group()[PrimaryContact = 'N']/MobNo)[1]"/>
                    </MobNo>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

One of the `MobNo` is not as in your desired result sample, I am not sure whether I did not fully understand your requirements or whether that sample is wrong.